# How to skip open Excel files when copying a directory in Azure Data Factory

Tags: excel, azure-data-factory

I have a data ingestion pipeline in Data Factory, which is fed a parameter. Based on this param, a Lookup activity returns file share directories along with a couple other pieces of metadata. These directories are then passed to a ForEach activity.

In this ForEach, a Copy Data activity exists. It has a source dataset (dataload_dir) and a sink dataset (our data lake). The source dataset has a dataset property, FilePattern, which is an expression: `@concat('*',pipeline().parameters.FilePattern,'*')`. The dataload_dir source dataset takes a FilePattern parameter and has a File Path property of `@item().DS_Directory_Name / @dataset().FilePattern`. The FilePattern param is part of the metadata grabbed above.

As an example, the ForEach is passed a DS_Directory_Name of `\\root\directoryA\subdirectoryB\` and a FilePattern of `.*x`. The Copy Data activity then loads all of the Excel files within subdirectoryB to our Data Lake.

This has been working as expected, but we have now run into an issue where the pipeline errors out because a user has one of the Excel files open and therefore locked. Any ideas on a way around this? Because we have this set up as a directory loader, there's no step that outputs the files top be copied so I can't just filter out files that start with ~$. Also, this Copy Data activity is already in a ForEach so I can't add a sub ForEach activity in Data Factory. I can't use Fault Tolerance in the Copy Data activity because again, it's loading a directory not a file/table. I'm open to suggestions here.

Comment: where I have wanted a sub ForEach I create another pipeline and call it in the first ForEach.  You can handle the error in the pipleline - look at connecting to the OnFail output of an activity.

Comment: please can you add images what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Scott- I was trying to avoid creating another pipeline, but it seems like that may be the only way to go. The issue with the OnFail is that if there are 5 Excel files and one of them is open (locked), I still need to have the other 4 get loaded. But right now, the whole thing errors out.

Comment: to iterate over folders and again on files you had to use two for each loops and for that you have to use another pipeline. or you can use similar naming convention and then use wildcard path to filter files.

Answer (score 2):

- The **ForEach activity** (in this case) used to copy each Excel file from Source directory into destination with directory. In case any file is open, the copy activity usually fails.
- But when a copy activity inside foreach fails, the pipeline execution does not fail/stop. It throws an error for that particular copy activity that fails, but it continues the execution of copy activity for remaining files.

Look at the following demonstration for clear understanding.

- The following inspect file under f1 folder is open in my system.
  [image]
- Inside Foreach, I have a copy activity along with  `wait`  activity (wait executes only if copy activity fails)
  [image]
- The first iteration of copy activity fails as the f1 folder contains file that is open in my system. And yet the pipeline runs successfully without failing. When I execute this pipeline, it completes successfully without any errors. The following is the debug output.
  [image]
  [image]

When I tried to get metadata from each folder, I got four files whereas F1 folder contain only three files, but one file is already open in my system it takes that file with `~$` prefix
[image]

**For this file to copy It throws an error for that particular copy activity that fails, but it continues the execution of copy activity for remaining files.**

In output I got all the Excel files copied from folder to destination except that file which is open in system.
[image]
[image]

**Note** - To iterate over folders and again on files you had to use two for each loop and for that you have to use another child pipeline inside parent pipeline.